# DirectX - a triangle is not displayed on a background

Tags: c++, directx

I dont know what is wrong in this code. The application should display a triangle on a blue background. The only thing that displays is the blue background.
D3DGame class inherits from D3DApp.

part of D3DApp.cpp:

```
void D3DApp::onResize() {

    assert(devCon);
    assert(dev);
    assert(swapChain);

    ReleaseCOM(renderTargetView);
    ReleaseCOM(depthStencilView);
    ReleaseCOM(depthStencilBuffer);

    swapChain->ResizeBuffers(1, width, height, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0);
    ID3D11Texture2D* _backBuffer;
    swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&_backBuffer));
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(_backBuffer, 0, &renderTargetView);
    ReleaseCOM(_backBuffer);

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC _depthStencilDesc;

    _depthStencilDesc.Width = width;
    _depthStencilDesc.Height = height;
    _depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    _depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    _depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;

    if (enable4xMsaa)
    {
        _depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
        _depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = x4MsaaQuality - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        _depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        _depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    }

    _depthStencilDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    _depthStencilDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    _depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    _depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    dev->CreateTexture2D(&_depthStencilDesc, 0, &depthStencilBuffer);
    dev->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencilBuffer, 0, &depthStencilView);

    devCon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTargetView, depthStencilView);

    screenViewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    screenViewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    screenViewport.Width = static_cast<float>(width);
    screenViewport.Height = static_cast<float>(height);
    screenViewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    screenViewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    devCon->RSSetViewports(1, &screenViewport);
}

bool D3DApp::init() {
    if (!initWND())
        return false;
    showWND();

    UINT _dev_flag = 0;
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
    _dev_flag = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
        0,
        driverType,
        0,
        _dev_flag,
        0, 0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &dev,
        &featurelLevel,
        &devCon);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(0, "Nie mozna utworzyc urzadzenia!", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC _sw_desc;
    _sw_desc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    _sw_desc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    _sw_desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    _sw_desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    _sw_desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    _sw_desc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    _sw_desc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    if (enable4xMsaa) {
        _sw_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
        _sw_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = x4MsaaQuality - 1;
    }
    else {
        _sw_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        _sw_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    }

    _sw_desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    _sw_desc.BufferCount = 1;
    _sw_desc.Windowed = true;
    _sw_desc.OutputWindow = windowHandle;
    _sw_desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    _sw_desc.Flags = 0;

    IDXGIDevice* dxgiDevice = 0;
    dev->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&dxgiDevice);

    IDXGIAdapter* dxgiAdapter = 0;
    dxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void**)&dxgiAdapter);

    IDXGIFactory* dxgiFactory = 0;
    dxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&dxgiFactory);

    dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain(dev, &_sw_desc, &swapChain);

    ReleaseCOM(dxgiDevice);
    ReleaseCOM(dxgiAdapter);
    ReleaseCOM(dxgiFactory);

    onResize();

    return true;
}
```

part of D3DGame.cpp:

```
bool D3DGame::buildGeoBuffers() {
    Vertex _vertices[] = {
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) }
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC _vbd;
    _vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    _vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex)* 3;
    _vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    _vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    _vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
    _vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA _sub_s;
    _sub_s.pSysMem = _vertices;
    HRESULT hr1 = dev->CreateBuffer(&_vbd, &_sub_s, &triangleVB);
    if (FAILED(hr1)) {
        MessageBox(0, "Nie mozna stworzyc bufora wierzcholkow trojkata!", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    //bufor indeksow
    UINT indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC _ibd;
    _ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    _ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT)* 36;
    _ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    _ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    _ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
    _ibd.StructureByteStride = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA _sub_s_indx;
    _sub_s_indx.pSysMem = indices;
    HRESULT hr2 = dev->CreateBuffer(&_ibd, &_sub_s_indx, &indexB);
    if (FAILED(hr2)) {
        MessageBox(0, "Nie mozna stworzyc bufora indeksow!", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool D3DGame::buildEffects() {
    DWORD shaderFlags = 0;
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG;
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#endif

    ID3D10Blob* compiledShader = 0;
    ID3D10Blob* compilationMsgs = 0;
    HRESULT hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile("color.fx", 0, 0, 0, "fx_5_0", shaderFlags,
        0, 0, &compiledShader, &compilationMsgs, 0);

    if (compilationMsgs != 0) {
        MessageBoxA(0, (char*)compilationMsgs->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);
        ReleaseCOM(compilationMsgs);
    }

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(0, "Nie mozna skompilowac pliku color.fx", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader->GetBufferSize(),
        0, dev, &effect);

    ReleaseCOM(compiledShader);

    eTech = effect->GetTechniqueByName("ColorTech");

    return true;
}

void D3DGame::buildVertexLay()
{
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexDesc[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };

    D3DX11_PASS_DESC passDesc;
    eTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);
    dev->CreateInputLayout(vertexDesc, 2, passDesc.pIAInputSignature,
        passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &inputLay);
}

bool D3DGame::init() {
    if (!D3DApp::init())
        return false;

    buildGeoBuffers();
    buildEffects();
    buildVertexLay();

    return true;
}

void D3DGame::draw() {
    float _colors[] = {
        0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f
    };

    devCon->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, _colors);
    devCon->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    devCon->IASetInputLayout(inputLay);
    devCon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devCon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &triangleVB, &stride, &offset);
    devCon->IASetIndexBuffer(indexB, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    D3DX11_TECHNIQUE_DESC techDesc;
    eTech->GetDesc(&techDesc);

    for (UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; ++p) {
        eTech->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0, devCon);
        devCon->DrawIndexed(3, 0, 0);
    }

    HRESULT hr = swapChain->Present(0, 0);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(0, "blad podczas zamiany buforow lancucha wymiany!", 0, 0);
    }
}

int D3DGame::run() {

    MSG msg = { 0 };

    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        } else {
            draw();
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Effect source:

```
struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL  : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH  : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout;

    // Transform to homogeneous clip space.
    //vout.PosH = mul(float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);
    vout.PosH = float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f);
    // Just pass vertex color into the pixel shader.
    vout.Color = vin.Color;

    return vout;
}

float4 PS(VertexOut pin) : SV_Target
{
    return pin.Color;
}

technique11 ColorTech
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_5_0, VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_5_0, PS() ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: At least check the results of the functions you call for errors.

Comment: When you build your DEBUG config, do you get any output in the Debug messages from the debug device? BTW, it appears you are using the Effects 11 system. You should make sure you are using the latest version from [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) which would allow you to use D3DX11CreateEffectFromFile directly (and avoids dependences on the [legacy D3DX11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx) library).